# TypeError: Parameter must be a string, not object

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to make a function return a string but all it does is return an object. I can't use the `.toString()` method either.

```
currentEnvironment: string = "beta";
serverURL: string = this.setServerURL(this.currentEnvironment);
URL: string = this.serverURL;

async setServerURL(env: string): Promise<string> {
  const myText: string = 'https://abcqwer.com';
  return myText;
}


async login(): Promise<void> {
  console.log('Login URL is: ' + this.URL.toString());
  await browser.get(this.URL);
};
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object

Comment: `Promise<string>` is not of type `string`. You need to wait for the Promise to resolve, or make `setServerURL` not async (since it doesn't seem to be doing any asynchronous work).

Comment: I am new to protractor and don't know how to do that. Removing async would cause the code to run out of sync I guess. Without the promise resolving how am I getting the error - TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object

Comment: Right now, you could change your code to `serverURL: string = 'https://abcqwer.com';`, remove `setServerURL` altogether, and see no difference. You may want to [edit] your question to show what actually happens in that function and perhaps we could advise you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method `this.setServerURL(this.currentEnvironment)` returns `Promise<string>` instead `string`. But why you need `setServerURL()` to be `async`? If you don't do any promise interaction you can re-write it:

```
setServerURL(env: string): string {
  const myText: string = 'https://abcqwer.com';
  return myText;
}
```

Imagine that you need do some `promise` things and your `setServerURL()` returns `Promise<string>`:

```
currentEnvironment = "beta"; // here typescript understand that variable has string type
serverURL: Promise<string> = this.setServerURL(this.currentEnvironment);
URL: Promise<string> = this.serverURL;

async setServerURL(env: string): Promise<string> {
  const myText: string = 'https://abcqwer.com';
  return myText; // even if 'myText' is string this method will return Promise<string> because it method has async keyword
}


async login(): Promise<void> {
  const url = await this.URL;
  console.log('Login URL is: ' + url);
  await browser.get(url);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I removed async and it works fine. I am relatively new to the async await approach so didn't reason much about the async for setServerURL. Thanks again.